# How to pass input text as parameter to javascript onblur event?

Tags: javascript, html, input

This is the code for an input text field. What I want is to call the "checkDateFormat" function with the text input as a parameter when the user leaves the field.

Here is the code I've written:

```
Fecha de prueba: <input type="text" name="date_t" id="date_t" value="22/08/2014" onblur="checkDateFormat(this.date_t.value)"><br>
```

However I'm sure the function isn't even called.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It should be `this.value`. That's all.

Comment: please use `this.value`  it will pass the value in the textbox on the event

Comment: Do you have any errors in the console ? It should work as expected, provided you change `onblur="checkDateFormat(this.date_t.value)"` to `onblur="checkDateFormat(this.value)"`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try to use,

```
 onblur="checkDateFormat(this.value)"
```

Instead of

```
 onblur="checkDateFormat(this.date_t.value)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I'll check it as the right answer as soon as the Webpage lets me!!!

Answer (score 1):

Try `checkDateFormat(this.value)` instead.